# `handleMessage` is called after `afterConnectionClosed ` in Spring Boot Web Sockets

Tags: java, websocket, spring-websocket

I have a nasty bug in my Spring Boot application that uses web sockets. Randomly it happens that in my `MyWebSocketHandler` class overridden methods `handleTextMessage` or `handleBinaryMessage` methods are called after `afterConnectionClosed`.

I supposed that it was something with a client but multiple clients caused the same issue.

Here is a simplified code that I have.

```java
@Component
public class MyWebSocketHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {

    private Map<String, ClientSession> activeSessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        activeSessions.put(session.getId(), clientSession);
        // doing work
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        activeSessions.remove(session.getId())

        // doing work
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
         checkSession(session); // Random Exception here

         // doing work
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleBinaryMessage(WebSocketSession session, BinaryMessage message) throws Exception {
         checkSession(session); // Random Exception here

         // doing work
    }

    private void checkSession(WebSocketSession session){
        if(activeSessions.get(session.getId() == null){
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

`afterConnectionClosed` shows close status `1000` and in the same millisecond new request with the same `sessionId` arrives to `handleTextMessage` or `handleBinaryMessage` and exception is thrown as the record was already removed from `activeSessions` map.

Any ideas about the possible reasons of this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

use something like this for your sessions :

```
 synchronized (session) {
                    do something with session
                }
```